# Allowance Log for excel based on duty hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aAHL.png)I am looking for a way to add a formula/method that will help me set allowance based on my duty hours. If I work less than 8 hours it's $50 8-24 is $100 and anything greater than 24 is $100+$4.11155 for every hour after 24.

the formula I used for the rate is
=IF(D2<=0,"$0.00",IF(D2<=8,"$50",IF(D2>8,"$100",IF(D2<=24,"$100",IF(D2>24,"$4.11155")))))

and the allowance is
=IF(E2="$4.11155","$(4.11155*D2)",IF(E2="$100","$100",IF(E2="$50","$50",IF(E2="$0.00","$0.00"))))

Comment: That looks pretty simple to me... Do you have any attempts?

Comment: It's also not clear exactly which calculation you are trying to perform. An example would go a long way here.

Comment: Less than 8 hours is $50/hr, 8-24 hours is a flat $100, and over 24 is $100+$4.15/hr? This calculation makes no sense... This would mean for example working 7 hours would earn you $350, working 8 hours would only earn you $100, and working 26 hours would earn you $108.30...

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 It certainly could have been worded better, but it can make sense xD

Comment: Ok basically...if I work less than 8 hours I get paid $50 flat and the same for 8-24 its $100 flat. above 24 is factored by $4.11155/hr... my initial comment i did say was per hour which was my mistake. only after 24 its considered per hour.

Comment: I have updated the initial comment with my attempt and details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(D2=0,0,IF(D2<8,50,IF(AND(D2>=8,D2<=24),100,IF(D2>24,100+((D2-24)*4.11155),""))))
```

Your formula would result in anything over 8 hours being 100, because that statement would evaluate as true before it gets to the next statement. And you also state that less than 8 hours is 50 but you use <= 8, so I changed that part.

Comment: Oh yeah. Your first formula accounts for negative hours for some reason, so if you need to do that just change the first if statement to IF(D2<=0,0, ...